# Yii 2 GridView Link Not Working

Tags: url, hyperlink, yii2

I have this code in my index.php in my **view**:

```
<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create Invoice', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],    
        //'inv_id',
        'cust_name',
        'currency',
        'inv_date',
        'inv_duedate',
        'prod_name',
        //'prod_desc',
        //'prod_quanity',
        'prod_price',
        //'prod_tax',
        //'amount',
        //'subtotal',
        'total',
        [
            'attribute' => 'image',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                //return Html::a($data->image, $data->image, $data->image);
                return Html::a(Html::encode($data->image),$data->image);
                //return Html::a($data->image, $data->image, array('target' => '_blank')); 
                //return Html::a(Html::encode('file'),'invoice/index');
            }
        ],
        //'poso_num',
        //'subheading',
        //'footer',
        //'memo',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I have already displayed the link/path of a specific file, when I click it, nothing happens. When I hover it, I can see the link, example: `file:///C:/wamp3/www/basicaccounting/web/pdf/attachment.pdf`, in the status bar (lower left corner of the page). I also tried right click + Open in New Tab, the url is just `about:blank`.

I also tried each of those commented return statements, still the same results.

Any thoughts about this?

**Edit**:

My problem is with my file path i.e. file:///C:/wamp3/www/basicaccounting/web/pdf/attachment.pdf
My path in the link needs to be relative to the document root i.e. /basicaccounting/web/pdf/attachment.pdf, and not in C drive.

So I tried:

```
'value' => function($data){
    $basepath = str_replace('\\', '/', Yii::$app->basePath).'/web/';
    $path = str_replace($basepath, '', $data->file);
    return Html::a($data->file, $path, array('target'=>'_blank'));
}
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: What exactly is stored in `$data->image`? Could you provide an example? And example of desired output.

Comment: @arogachev I used `var_dump()` in displaying what's inside `$date->image`. Here's an example: `string 'C:/wamp3/www/basicaccounting/web/uploads/dcc.jpg' (length=48)`

Comment: And what link you want create from that string?

Comment: @arogachev I want it when I click that link, it will open in a new tab, displaying the file (pdf file).

Comment: I edited my question. It's now fine. :)

Comment: In this case you can issue this as answer so the others can know too.

Comment: Yes, I just did. I almost forgot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved my own problem.

My problem is with my file path i.e. file:///C:/wamp3/www/basicaccounting/web/pdf/attachment.pdf
My path in the link needs to be relative to the document root i.e. /basicaccounting/web/pdf/attachment.pdf, and not in C drive.

So I tried:

```
'value' => function($data){
$basepath = str_replace('\\', '/', Yii::$app->basePath).'/web/';
$path = str_replace($basepath, '', $data->file);
return Html::a($data->file, $path, array('target'=>'_blank'));
```

Now it works fine. Thanks everyone!